# Binding data of an SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, data-binding, ado.net

I am creating a navigation window in a wpf interface. I have in the initial page a Listbox with a few names and a button which links to a page displaying data of the selected Name. I would like to use as a source of the Databinding a database, in the following way:

When the user clicks the button, the displaying window appears and it presents data coming from a SQL query. I need therefore to bind displaying data to the results of a SQL query. I would like to use ADO.NET, the connected layer and SqlDataReader . How should the binding be in terms of xaml Code? A similar example is in [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752299.aspx) using though XML source.

Answer (score 0):

There is a class in WPF that loads a lot of data. You bind the control to the data loader ( I can't remember the name). It is all done through XML code. You don't have to write any C# code. Goes like this:

It is pretty straightforward. Go to MSDN website and search wpf data binding. It is all done in XML. There is almost no difference in calling data from sql, web. It is all taken care of in WPF.